# Who benefits from FIA fees and fines?

Tags: finances, formula-1

Frequently we see fines being levied in Formula One (for example, for unsafe pit lane releases, a team or driver may receive a fine of several thousand dollars [such as Mercedes earlier this year](http://www.gpupdate.net/en/f1-news/285539/mercedes-fined-10-000-for-unsafe-pit-release/)). I also note that [FIA entry fees are pretty massive too](http://www.gpupdate.net/en/f1-news/286579/fia-ramps-up-entry-fees-for-2013-season/).

How does this money get spent? I'm presuming it's not just to pay for Jean Todt's private jets and limos but I've never heard or read anything about it filtering down to grassroots sport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The money goes into the budget for the operating expenses of the International Automobile Federation per this article : [Formula 1 Fines](http://formula1.about.com/od/formula1101/a/F1-Teams-And-Drivers-Have-To-Pay-Traffic-Fines-Too.htm). The team of the offending driver must pay the fine within 48 hours via bank transfer though this may later get taken from the offending drivers paycheck